# How to initialize a non-nullable generic type property (or field) (c# 8 or 9)

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types, c#-9.0

I'm converting some older code to c# 8 and 9 with nullable enabled. I've run into some trouble with generics. Here's an example. The older class has an unconstrained type parameter:

```
public class WeightedValue1<T>
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This gives CS8618: Non-nullable property 'Value' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor.

That's great; it's preventing exactly the sort of bug the feature is designed to catch - users dereferencing .Value and getting a NullReferenceException.  The problem is it's hard to initialize the property correctly. In the old world it would be:

```
public class WeightedValue2<T>
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; } = default;
}
```

This gives CS8601 Possible null reference assignment. As well it should! I haven't actually solved the problem.
Even if T is *non-nullable* string , callers get NRE with ***no warning***:

```
[TestClass]
public class NreTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void NonNullableString_ThrowsNre()
    {
        Assert.ThrowsException<NullReferenceException>(() => new WeightedValue2<string>().Value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Just for completeness, notice that specifying the notnull constraint doesn't change anything.

```
public class WeightedValue3<T>
    where T : notnull
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; } = default;
}

[TestClass]
public class NreTest3
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ConstrainedString_ThrowsNre()
    {
        Assert.ThrowsException<NullReferenceException>(() => new WeightedValue3<string>().Value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

And of course using the null-forgiving operator (!) hides the warning but doesn't help the caller at all.

```
public class WeightedValue4<T>
    where T : notnull
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; } = default!;
}
[TestClass]
public class NreTest4
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ForgivenString_ThrowsNre()
    {
        Assert.ThrowsException<NullReferenceException>(()=> new WeightedValue4<string>().Value.ToLower());
    } 
}
```

Right, so the problem is really that default of string is null, whether we want it to be allowed or not. And nothing we tell the compiler will let it change that. So we have to initialize it with something. Since it's a generic unconstrained T, we can't find any valid values. We *have* to push this onto the caller. All my existing callers will be using the object initializer syntax, so the new c#9 "init" properties would seem a great fit.

```
public class WeightedValue5<T>
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; init; }
}
```

Sigh. Unfortunately init doesn't do what I want. It means you can't call the setter after object creation, but it doesn't force you to actually initialize the property. It's doubly frustrating because the compiler ***knows*** it needs initialization.

```
[TestClass]
public class NreTest5
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void InitOnlySetter_Compiles_AndThrowsNre()
    {
        Assert.ThrowsException<NullReferenceException>(() => new WeightedValue5<string>().Value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Here's a version that at least does the job of warning callers about the nullability. But it requires changing every existing call site. And it has the usual annoyances when you start having lots of properties and multiple constructors to initialize.

```
public class WeightedValue6<T>
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; }

    public WeightedValue6(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I've also explored the attribute annotations but I don't see how they can help. And AFAIK the new record types have the same problem despite their goal of reducing boilerplate for simple reference types.

Am I crazy? Is it really true that the only way I can initialize generic fields with definitely non-null values is to make every caller specify them manually? And the only way to force that is with full-fat constructors? (and of course setting specific warnings as errors.)

If that's the case, is it wrong to wish the compiler would rewrite my version with init; *as if* it had the full constructor?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Either you want the property to be nullable or not. It _seems_ like, from the above, you want it non-nullable. But in that case, _of course_ there will need to be a mechanism to initialize the object at construction with the non-null value. How else could it be? And what's wrong with that? Yes, it's sometimes annoying to have to port unsafe code to a safer paradigm. So? I fail to see what the actual _problem_ is here. There's a lot of rambling, but no indication of what practical solution might answer whatever question is supposed to be here.

Comment: I like the question++; it highlights the change in mindset and design when you go the non-nullable route. I agree with @Peter though; it seems like you're trying to code to standard you're not willing to enforce.

Comment: I want to enforce the nullability checks. I've wished for the feature a long time and find it useful in many cases. I'm surprised it's as difficult to use with generics as I've found it, and hoping that I've missed a tool or technique that makes for cleaner code than I'm writing.

Comment: IMHO, the features are not guided enough but given that it's introduced so late in the game it's unreasonable to force an implementation that would, say, require an `Option<T>`. But even then, trying to get an `Option<T>` from a `null` value would be `Exception`al as it is viewed as a developer error.

Comment: Record types reduce the boiler by a lot and force you to provide values `public record WeightedValue<T>(double Weight, T Value);`

Comment: I think the question was excellently worded and exactly describes my own situation and frustration, I see no reason for the given downvotes. The new and wonderful C# 8 Nullable feature is an absolute pain with generics. In truth, if I've constrained my generic argument T as notnull, shouldn't that imply default(T) is a non-null value? This is all a mess and I too hope to find a pattern or language tool to deal with it without adding tons of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned records not being able to solve the problem, but I think they reduce the boilerplate for this quite a bit.

```cs
public record WeightedValue<T>(double Weight, T Value);
```

If you pass null to value, the compiler is going to complain with nullable reference types on. There is also the `with` syntax that does give you a bit of the `init` feel, but you need to have a value you are copying from.

```cs
var weightedValue = new WeightedValue<string>(0, "Hello"); // fine
weightedValue = new WeightedValue<string>(0, null); // compiler warning
weightedValue = weightedValue with { Value = null }; // compiler warning
```

I like object initialization as well, but named parameters look pretty good to. The only place they don't work is in expression trees (which is quite annoying).

```cs
var weightedValue = new WeightedValue<string>(
    Weight: 0, 
    Value: "Hello"
);
```

Another potential option using the `with` syntax is to create a default value to init your types and then call it and change parameters you are interested in with your object.

```
public static WeightedValue<string> defaultWeightedString = new(0, "");

//...

var weightedValue = defaultWeightedString with { Weight = 10 }; // string Value initialized
```

I see lots of potential here. However, if we had some sort of `{ get; init required; }` to force initialization on instantiation, that would be great.

**Update** It looks like there is a proposal for this.

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3630

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4209